# Multi color TD in html/php?

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to find a way to make my td or table multi color.

```
echo "<table  padding=\"0\" spacing=\"0\" 
  style=\"background-color:yellow; width: 100%; margin-left: 2px; 
  width: 100%; line-height: 80% ;\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class=\"bgfiller\">
  <font style=\"color: black;  font-size:90%; \" >
   ".$rowbis['Lnaam']." - ".$rowbis['Type_name']."</font>
  </td></tr>";
```

My bgfiller style looks like this:

```
.bgfiller{
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1 ; 
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is make a block that is yellow with a small block in it of 10px (will be set by a variable in a later state) and with some text over it.

So you will get something like a progress bar with text over it. But the text has to use the complete width of the table and just the 10px.

Anyone got a clue on how I could get this to work?

Comment: I extremely recommend using a Javascript lib like jQuery, Dojo, Prototype, MooTools etc. they all include such things as out-of-the-box thing.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3mGfC/

Comment: @daemonfire300 There's really no need for JavaScript when basic CSS will do. JavaScript libraries are great... for JavaScript programming. Not for basic page layout and stylization.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple a progress bar is something dynamic, based on changing data. This is a case of JS usage. At least I think so. :)

Comment: CHANGING the progress bar may or may not be dynamic (certainly if it's changing while the visitor interacts with the page, JavaScript is an excellent solution). But that's independent of how the elements are styled.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please eliminate the `<font>` tag. There's no reason for it when you can just add `font-size: 90%; color: black;` to your existing `.bgfiller` rule.

But to answer your question, I'd suggest something like this:

```
<div style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; position: relative;">
    Hello There I am Text
    <div style="width: 30px; background: yellow; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/knWuf/

Comment: And don't use tables for layouts, they're for tables of data.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is much cleaner but what exactly are you trying to do with the text?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WVvLD/

```
<div><span>Progress</span><div>
```

```
div {
    background-color: yellow;
}
span {
    background-color: red;
    display:block;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep working with tables, this may be a solution:

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
        <td><span></span>this is an text</td>     
 </tr>
</table>
```

and the style

```
td{
background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-2;
}
td span{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:darkred;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WVvLD/34/